# Metrics for image pull time for GKE cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, metrics, containerd

Is there a way to get metrics for image pull time on GKE?

Found this PR for `containerd` at least: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/pull/7313, but couldn't find anything related in the GKE docs.

Our cluster does use the `cos_containerd` node image.